# Implications of direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra

If $L_1 \oplus L_2 = L_1 \oplus L_3$ , then $L_2 = L_3$. $L_1,L_2,L_3$ are subspaces of $R^n,n \geq 3$

It should be false, but I don't see why.

Direct sum means that $\dim L_1 + \dim L_2 = \dim L_1 + \dim L_3 \Rightarrow \dim L_2 = \dim L_3$. I understand that same dimension doesn't mean that subspaces are the same. It's hard for me to (sorry for this word) believe that one could get the same subspace as a result of different additions.

For example, take linear span of basis vectors $e_1, e_2$ in $R^3$. How could we get $R^3$? By adding the linear span of $e_3$ via direct sum, i.e. $<e_1,e_2> \oplus <e_3>$. The question is what else could be added to $<e_1,e_2>$ to get $R^3$?

Comment: You wrote $L_1\oplus L_2=L_1\oplus L_2$. That's always true.

Comment: "The question is what else could be added" <- $<e_3 + e_2>$ for example.

Comment: Just in $\mathbb{R}^2$, fix a one-dimensional subspace $L_1$. Then for every one dimensional subspace $L\neq L_1$, we have $L_1\oplus L=\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct sum doesn't require that the spaces are orthogonal.

Consider in $\Bbb R^2$, $L_1=\operatorname{span}\{(1,0)\}$, $L_2=\operatorname{span}\{(0,1)\}$, and $L_3=\operatorname{span}\{(1,1)\}$. Then we have $L_1\oplus L_2=L_1\oplus L_3=L_2\oplus L_3=\Bbb R^2$. Clearly $L_2\neq L_3$.

If you require that the sum would be between *orthogonal* spaces then it's a whole other thing.